# Docker pull can authenticate but run cannot

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I built, tagged & published my first (ever) Docker image to Quay:

```
docker build -t myapp .
docker tag <imageId> quay.io/myorg/myapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
docker login quay.io
docker push quay.io/myorg/myapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I then logged into Quay.io to confirm the tagged image was successfully pushed, and it was. So then I SSHed into a brand-spanking-new AWS EC2 instance and [followed their instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html) to install Docker:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y docker
sudo service docker start
sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
sudo docker info
```

Interestingly enough the `sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user` command doesn't seem to work as advertised as I still need to append `sudo` to all my commands...

So I try to pull my tagged image:

```
sudo docker pull quay.io/myorg/myapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Please login prior to pull:
Username: myorguser
Password: <password entered>
1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Pulling from myorg/myapp
<hashNum1>: Pull complete 
<hashNum2>: Pull complete 
<hashNum3>: Pull complete 
<hashNum4>: Pull complete 
<hashNum5>: Pull complete 
<hashNum6>: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:<longHashNum>
Status: Downloaded newer image for quay.io/myorg/myapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

So far, so good (I guess!). Let's see what images my local Docker engine knows about:

```
sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Hmmm...that doesn't seem right. Oh well, let' try running a container for my (successfully?) pulled image:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 8080:80 -d --name myapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT myapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Unable to find image 'myapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: repository myapp not found: does not exist or no pull access.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

**Any idea where I'm going awry?**

Comment: you need to use `docker images` to check what images you have pulled. `docker ps` shows you the running containers.

Comment: try `sudo docker run -it -p 8080:80 -d --name myapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT quay.io/myorg/myapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: One important thing about running the `usermod` command: you need to log out for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list images, you need to use: `docker images`

When you pull, the image has the same tag. So if you wish to run, you will need to use:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 8080:80 -d --name myapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT quay.io/myorg/myapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

If you wish to use a short name, you need to retag it after the `docker pull`:

```
sudo docker tag quay.io/myorg/myapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT myapp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

After that, your `docker run` command will work. Note that `docker ps` is for containers that are running (or have exited in the recent past if used with `-a`)